# How to memoize with Map()

Tags: javascript, function, caching, callback, memoization

I am currently stuck on a problem with the memoize function in JavaScript. The last 2 tests don't pass. I will be more then happy for assistance.

The problem is the following:

- Write a memoize function that takes in a required callback function and an optional resolver function. The memoize function returns a memoized version of the callback function, which is defined as follows:
- All of the return values of the memoized function are cached. If the memoized callback is called with an existing cache key (defined below), then that cached value is returned without invoking the callback again.
- The cache key is defined based on the optional resolver function. If a resolver function is not provided, then the cache key is the result of passing the memoized function arguments to JSON.stringify as an array. If a custom resolver function is provided, then the arguments should be individually passed to that function instead, and its return value will be the cache key (note that this can be of any type).
- The memoized function should also have three methods: clear(): Clears out the cache. delete(...args): Deletes the cache entry corresponding to the passed arguments if one exists. has(...args): Returns a boolean of true if the cache has an entry corresponding to the passed arguments, otherwise false. For simplicity, you don't need to worry about binding a this context (i.e., you can assume that the callback doesn't reference this).

*The callback function look like this:*

```
const callback = (...args) => args;
```

*And this is the input and the result that should be returned*

```
const memoized = memoize(callback);
memoized(123); // calls callback, returns 123
memoized(123); // returns 123
memoized(123, 'abc'); // calls callback, returns [123, 'abc']
```

```
const memoized2 = memoize(callback, args => args[0]);
memoized2(123); // calls callback, returns 123
memoized2(123); // returns 123
memoized2(123, 'abc'); // returns 123
memoized('abc', 123); // calls callback, returns ['abc', 123]
memoized2('abc'); // returns ['abc', 123]
```

I've stored all arguments in cache and when the same argument is called the result will be returned from cache.

*This is my code*

```
function memoize(cb) {
    const memo = new Map();

    return function (...args) {
        const key = JSON.stringify(args);
        if (!memo.has(args)) {
            memo.set(key, cb(...args));
            return memo.get(key);
        }
        return memo.get(key);
    };
}
```

*And this are the tests*

```
const chai = require("chai");
const spies = require("chai-spies");
const { expect } = chai;

chai.use(spies);
const spy = () => chai.spy(() => {});

const { memoize } = require("../memoize.js");

describe("memoize", () => {
    it("callback without parameters is never called twice", () => {
        const callback = spy(() => {});
        const memoized = memoize(callback);
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(0);
        memoized();
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(1);
        memoized();
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(1);
        memoized();
        memoized();
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(1);
    });

    it("callback with a single parameter is handled properly", () => {
        const callback = spy((val) => val * 2);
        const memoized = memoize(callback);
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(0);
        const val1 = memoized(1);
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(1);
        expect(val1).to.equal(2);

        const val2 = memoized(1);
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(1);
        expect(val2).to.equal(2);

        const val3 = memoized(2);
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(2);
        expect(val3).to.equal(4);

        const val4 = memoized(2);
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(2);
        expect(val4).to.equal(4);

        const val5 = memoized(1);
        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(2);
        expect(val5).to.equal(2);
    });

    it("has function works as expected", () => {
        const callback = spy((...args) => args);
        const memoized = memoize(callback);

        expect(memoized.has()).to.be.false;
        expect(memoized.has(123)).to.be.false;
        expect(memoized.has(123, "abc")).to.be.false;

        memoized();
        expect(memoized.has()).to.be.true;

        memoized(123);
        expect(memoized.has(123)).to.be.true;

        memoized(123, "abc");
        expect(memoized.has(123, "abc")).to.be.true;

        expect(callback).to.have.been.called.exactly(3);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your `memoize()` function doesn't have an optional resolver

Comment: `if (!memo.has(args))` - Two arrays are never the same - regardless of their content. You have to test for the `key`

Comment: @Andreas I've tried to include the resolver with the spread operator. For example (...cb). Then I check if cb[1] exist, if so the resolver is used for his purpose. But nothing different happens. The tests are my hint, on that how the fn should work.

Comment: If you're doing `memo.set(key, cb(...args));` as well as `memo.get(key);` then surely `memo.has(args)` should be `memo.has(key)`, otherwise the code doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am gonna give solves 12 tests instead of 3, including your tests.

Try this:

```
const defaultResolver = (...args) => JSON.stringify(args);

export function memoize(fn, resolver = defaultResolver) {
  const cache = new Map();
  const memoized = (...args) => {
    const key = resolver(...args);
    if (cache.has(key)) {
      return cache.get(key);
    }
    const result = fn(...args);
    cache.set(key, result);
    return result;
  };
  memoized.clear = () => cache.clear();
  memoized.delete = (...args) => {
    const key = resolver(...args);
    cache.delete(key);
  };
  memoized.has = (...args) => {
    const key = resolver(...args);
    return cache.has(key);
  }
  return memoized;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually VERY close with code. There is just a minor thing that was missed though.

```js
function memoize(cb) {
    const memo = new Map();

    return function (...args) {
        const key = JSON.stringify(args);

        // Forgot to use the key here in the map
        if (!memo.has(key)) {
            memo.set(key, cb(...args));
            return memo.get(key);
        }
        return memo.get(key);
    };
}
```

You were creating a key, then just passing the args.